# MySQL syntax - IF / END IF

Tags: mysql, syntax

Can someone tell me what I am missing in terms of proper syntax? I don't know where to insert the second END IF to end the first IF.

Thanks.

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `item` WHERE `CharID` = argCharID AND (`Name` = 'LBlade' OR `Name` = 'DExe')) != 1) THEN
      BEGIN
        SET argOutMessage = "Aborted: need 1 LBlade or DExe";
        leave main_block;
      END;
    END IF;
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this...I want to check to see if there is either a 'LBlade' OR 'DExe' associated with the CharID in a specific table. If there isn't one, or alternatively, if there is more than one, I want to leave the main block and write the error message beginning with "Aborted:..."

Comment: remove the last ) from here 'DExe')) and I guess you should be through

Comment: Hi @Satya, if I do that unfortunately I get a syntax error where the command won't run (#1064 - near 'THEN BEGIN...'

Comment: mea culpa I missed the opening bracket before SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small suggestions for your code:

- Use `in` instead of comparisons with `or` (easier to read).
- You don't need `begin`/`end` for the `then`.
- Use single quotes for string constants.

The result is something like this:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM `item`
     WHERE `CharID` = argCharID AND `Name` IN ('LBlade', 'DExe')
    ) <> 1
   )
THEN
    SET argOutMessage = 'Aborted: need 1 LBlade or DExe';
    leave main_block;
END IF;
```

Note:  If you are looking for 0/1 things, then `exists` is more efficient than `count(*)`.